# PHP: Get timestamp from date format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS GMT+HH:MM

Tags: php, timestamp, date-format

I'm reading lines from a *.txt file and get strings (date formats) in this style:

```
2017-10-19 20:51:54 GMT+08:00
2020-03-31 13:19:31 GMT-08:00
2018-04-10 14:35:17 GMT
```

With the function **DateTime::createFromFormat**, I want to convert such lines into a time string. After that, I would like to get the timestamp with **getTimestamp();**. So, currently my code looks like this ($date is my read line):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
$timeStamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

When I try to do this, I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on bool in ...
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Edit: 
Regarding Gordon's comment, I also tried to add the missing parts ("GMT" => e and "+08:00" => P) as well, like this:

```
$date= DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s eP", $date);
```

Comment: You will need to add the GMT part as well. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: @Gordon Thanks for the comment, I just tried it but it didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the date provided does not match the format specified.

Add the following line after createFromFormat() call -

```
var_dump(DateTime::getLastErrors());
```

The above line will return the error. The error message is - "**Trailing data**". This is because of "GMT+08:00" in the string.

For processing it properly you should provide the optional third parameter to createFormFormat which is timezone and it expects it to be a DateTimeZone object. So update your createFromFormat function as -

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT+08:00');
$date = "2017-10-19 20:51:54";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date, $timezone);
```

I hope this helps. You will have to separate the date from the timezone and process it as mentioned above.